# Pandas groupby and subtract each element of a column by element in nth row

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe df as given below:

```
 country_code  count_date  confirmed_cases
0              AFG  2020-09-13          38641.0
1              AFG  2020-09-12          38606.0
2              AFG  2020-09-11          38572.0
3              AFG  2020-09-10          38544.0
4              AFG  2020-09-09          38520.0
...            ...         ...              ...
19521          ZWE  2020-06-03            206.0
19522          ZWE  2020-06-02            203.0
19523          ZWE  2020-06-01            178.0
19524          ZWE  2020-05-31            174.0
19525          ZWE  2020-05-30            149.0
```

After groupby country_code how do I create a new column which has confirmed_cases of each date subtracted by confirmed_cases n days earlier.

I tried

```
n = 7
df.groupby('country_code').confirmed_cases.transform(lambda x:x-x.iloc[::n])
```

which doesnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `shift`

```
n = 7
out = df['confirmed_cases'] - df.groupby('country_code').confirmed_cases.shift(n)
```

Update :

```
df.groupby('country_code').confirmed_cases.apply(lambda x:x-x.shift(n))
```

Comment: Thank you but actually I need to access the rows inside the lambda function for further calculation. Can you tell me how to do it?

Comment: @Naveed inlcude shift in lambda ~

Comment: Great. Guess we can use either apply or transform here.